# Dagger2 crashing on setText calling ViewModel

Tags: java, android, dagger, android-viewmodel

App builds but crashes at runtime with a null object reference. Been trying to debug it but can't locate the error but I know that if I remove the setText on the textview which calls a method to retrieve a String that then gets displayed in the MainActivity via a fragment (if I remove this no crash) which leads me to believe that my null object is something to do with how I havent instantiated the viewmodel. Unsure of how to do this.

tried removing and locating bufg from stacktrace which states that the null object reference is in onActivityCreated in the fragment but Dagger generates code this is where I'm lost as if I don't run it builds and shows no compile time error.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
@Inject
HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
TextView tvFrag;

public HomeFragment() {
}


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    tvFrag = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_frag);
    tvFrag.setText(homeViewModel.getConnection()); //HERE
}
```

}

```
@FragmentScope
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {


private DatabaseService databaseService;
private NetworkService networkService;
private NetworkHelper networkHelper;

@Inject
public HomeViewModel(DatabaseService ds, NetworkService ns, NetworkHelper nh){
    this.databaseService = ds;
    this.networkService = ns;
    this.networkHelper = nh;

}
public String getConnection(){
    return "Ben Mohammad Connected";
}
```

}

[image: StackTrace]

GitHub Link - https://github.com/BenMohammad/LearnDagger-STAGE_2-with-dagger-better

Should call the method getConnection() in the viewModel and retrieve a string and display on the fragment which has been added to MainActivity.

Thanks

Comment: Given the code as is, I'd say it's most likely the viewModel that is null. At which point do you inject the fragment with dagger?

Comment: Yeah you're right Fred I've uploaded the stackTrace I don't understand how to instantiate the viewmodel using Dagger....

Comment: Are you using dagger-android or just dagger?

Comment: implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't performed the dependency injection in that view . It could be :

```
AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
```

or :

```
((YourApplicationClass) getActivity().getApplication()).getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
```

(in case you are not using Dagger for Android ) , in your `onCreate` method.

In that case , Dagger will know that it has some dependencies to be injected in that fragment , in your case the `HomeViewModel` . Otherwise the `HomeViewModel` is still null untill you perform the DI

Comment: Getting there, "FragmentActivity cannot be cast to MyApplication" now it wont build Dagger is confusing I need to learn this. 
This is the fragment I have https://github.com/BenMohammad/LearnDagger-STAGE_2-with-dagger-better/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/bootcamp/learndagger/fragment/HomeFragment.java

Comment: Ok the above are just an example of how to perform dependency injection in your view. Just performe your DI there and done.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't inject `HomeViewModel` in your fragment.
try to use `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);` in your `onCreate` method.
method should look like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
}
```

Comment: You're right I haven't I don't know how to, with what I have already implemented I'm fairly sure its got to be the way I'm using Dagger missing something as everyone tells me to change to where I put the setText in onCreateView or onViewCreated etc none of that works. I tried Android SupportInjection and it doesnt build I will push to github. Any help or pointers appreciated.Thanks

Comment: your code has lot to change. To make `AndroidSupportInject.inject(this)` you need to add library to your gradle.

`implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger2Version"`
 
if you use the support libraries you need to add `annotationProcessor`  in your graddle.

    
`annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger2Version" `

Answer (score 2):

OK I think the answers (including mine ),have confused you more than you are .

The ViewModel must be initialized like this (I don't know what is in your Module but this is the right way) : In `onCreate`  method go :

```
HomeViewModel homeviewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
```

If you need to pass dependencies to your viewmodel , please use ViewModel Factory . Google yourself or just refer to [this link](https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/android-viewmodel-and-factoryprovider-good-way-to-manage-it-with-dagger-2-d9e20a07084c)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find `tv_frag` in the Parent Activity not the current fragment.

Change to:

```
tvFrag = getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_frag);
tvFrag.setText(homeViewModel.getConnection());
```

Comment: tried this before did again obviously didnt work still crashes I need to supply more details.Thanks